# Is MotherLoad available for iPhone?

Tags: ios

I really enjoy playing this miniclip game and I was wondering if they had it for iPhone.

Comment: whats up with the down vote?!?!!?

Comment: Downvoted without any constructive feedback, gotta love them, I fixed it for you.

Comment: So I wasn't the guy with the original down vote, but I'm going to downvote you too.  I don't think your question is wrong, and it's certainly site appropriate, I think it's just a poor quality question.  To find the answer I literally googled "MotherLoad for iPhone" and it was the first result. Now I know we don't require you do some research before asking, but that doesn't stop you from at least making a little bit of an effort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nope](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showpost.php?s=a3b5a28629e4063ea16cd9452c60de7b&p=276179&postcount=9).

[Apparently "I Dig It" is similar](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=712801), though.

Comment: Played I Dig It, it is very similar and a pretty good game.

Answer (score 0):

Motherload for the Wii is in the works and the developers said if it's successful enough they'll port it to other platforms.